# file_exists() not working. File gets uploaded

Tags: php, upload, file-exists

Seeking some help here.

For some reason the file_exists() doesn't work for me.

The file always gets uploaded and replacing the old file. It should show the message file already exists.

Thoughts?

Thanks
Avenue

```html
if (!empty($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action']=='save'){
      $path = "../uploads/";
      $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
      $uploadOK = 1;

      if (file_exists($path)) {
          $message = array("type" => "info", "message" => "file already exists.");
          $uploadOk = 0;
      }

      if ($uploadOk = 1) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
          $message = array("type" => "info", "message" => "File has been uploaded.");

        } else{
          $message = array("type" => "info", "message" => "Error please try again.");
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: $uploadOk = 1 is wrong .change to if($uploadOk == 1)

Comment: try with $uploadOk == 1

Comment: Thanks! It works, I have accidentally declared 2 variables. After fixing them and adding == it works as intended.